# symfony No route found for GET

Tags: php, regex, symfony, routes

No route found for "GET /category/wordone-wordtwo"

This is the error I get when I try to access

```
http://localhost/site/web/app_dev.php/category/wordone-wordtwo
```

Routing.yml:

```
csa_platform_category:
path:     /category/{slug}
defaults: { _controller: CSAPlatformBundle:Category:index }
requirements:
    slug: "~^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$~"
```

this requiremens slug for slugs like (wordone-wordtwo-wordtree)

> All routes work good. except this route: csa_platform_category

Comment: does it work if you remove the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

What if you get rid of the Tilde (~) and the double quotes:

```
csa_platform_category:
   path:     /category/{slug}
   defaults: { _controller: CSAPlatformBundle:Category:index }
   requirements:
      slug: '^[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$'
```

Try it - I'm not sure if that makes any difference.